# SSIS File Task Not Executing

Tags: ssis

I have built an SSIS package for picking up flat text files. Everything is running fine, the files are read and imported into a SQL database but I am having issues with the final File System Task step that does not seem to execute at all. I am not finding any errors while running the package locally on my computer and running out of ideas of what the issue might be.

**Here are some details about the package;**
[image: Package execution and File Task Config]

**My User::OutputFileName variable destination evaluates to;**
C:\Data Drop\Loaded\CM02-VCU-2023-10-23_20231025.txt

**My User:varFilePath variable source evaluates to;**
C:\Data Drop\CM02-VCU-2023-10-23.txt

Currently I am running VS Studio Enterprise 2019 locally as an admin, I have the ProtectionLevel set to DontSaveSensitive, and Run64BitRunetime set to True. The connections from the WorkOrder and VCU dataflow tasks are set to the default Logical AND Constraint with a Value of Success.

Anyone have any ideas of what else I can try to figure out what is going on here? I figured Id at least get a package failure or some type of error to give me an idea of what is going on but cant even find anything in the Windows Event logs.

Comment: The last step with the 2 arrows pointing to it?  I think you have to click on the green lines and change the constraint to be logical OR possibly (probably AND right now)  or something similar to allow it to execute.

Comment: Switching them to Logical OR did the trick. Not quite sure why it would need OR, figured a successful Dataflow would be just a single trigger for that but glad its working properly now. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment answered the question so moving here:

The last step with the 2 arrows pointing to it? I think you have to click on the green lines and change the constraint to be logical OR possibly (probably AND right now) or something similar to allow it to execute.

To do this you click the green flow arrows and get this box to update:
[image]